# Can I omit a colon and use a comma instead in this sentence to dramatize?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, colons

original sentence -> The purpose is to disclose some information

new sentence -> the purpose: to disclose some information

last version(I'm asking about) -> The purpose, to disclose information

Comment: Could you kindly express why I was down-voted for this?

Comment: I like the colon; so did Capt Kirk. "These are the voyages of the Starship Enterprise. Its five-year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations..." As for the downvote: I'm guessing that someone wondered why you didn't simply Google "usage of colon in sentence" and find your answer there (or, if you did, why you didn't better explain why you were still confused). It wasn't my downvote, but I can't say I find it unjustified, either. (@Kris: The apostrophe was an error in the version I pasted from; since I can't edit, I reposted this comment, error fixed).

Comment: I respect your opinion and taking the time to help me better understand the reasoning. Knowing this, I don't think it was warranted as I did search for it here and on google and obviously did not find a suitable answer. I don't see the point in discouraging new users from posting and learning without the benefit of guiding them in the right direction. Saying go 'google it up' is not the answer to everything.

Comment: @AWW: I see this discussion rather often on EL&U. I didn't say "Google it yourself" was the answer to your question, I said that you may have gotten downvoted because you didn't spend any time explaining what research you may have done. If you hover over the downvote arrow, you'll see a tip: "This question does not show any research effort." When someone asks a basic question without explaining _why_ they are confused, despite trying to find an answer first, then downvotes may happen. "Google it" isn't the answer, but, if you're unwilling to do that much, don't be shocked at a downvote or two.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first expresses your meaning well. The second would be fine as a heading. The third is confusing.

Comment: You'd generally use the form "The purpose, to disclose information" after a co-ordinating phrase, thus: "The format is that of a formal report; the purpose, to disclose information."

Answer (score 3):

You'd generally use the form

> The purpose, to disclose information

after a coordinating phrase; thus:

> The format is that of a formal report; the purpose, to disclose information.